# SAS CART Analysis

Tags: tree, statistics, sas, regression, statsmodels

To get started with decision trees I want SAS to produce a decision tree from a data set with one dependent, binary variable (disease 0/1) and several independent, continuous variables (usually I would run logistic regression for these data). The tree should "decide" which variables are important risk factors for the disease. Any hints for a beginner in decision trees but fairly experienced SAS user (no access to SAS enterprise miner)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use SAS EG and Miner, you can use function in the Task->Data mining->Rapid Predictive Modeler to run decesion tree. In the process, it allows you to choose model type, CART is in it. Then you export your process to MINER for tweaking your settings. 
Hope it could help.